# GPG error when running apt-get update

Tags: apt, update-manager

I have looked at many of the existing answers to this question and tried their suggestions, but they do not solve or answer the issue I am having.

When I run apt-get update, I receive the following:

```
GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid:  NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

I have tried the following:

```
 sudo -i

 apt-get clean

 cd /var/lib/apt

 mv lists lists.old

 mkdir -p lists/partial

 apt-get clean

 apt-get update
```

and other posts describe using apt-key, but the error is not specifying a key.

It seems that there is no key at all?

Is there a command that would download a fresh key?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by changing the repositories.

I found a post where someone suggested changing the /etc/apt/sources.list, and change all instances of precise to raring.

Original:
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

New:
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted


Being somewhat of a linux beginner, my understanding is that raring is a newer set of Ubuntu files than the precise.

After making the change, I was able to run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade successfully with no errors.

Thanks

Comment: I appologize for the bad formatting on the last comment.  Not sure why it scrunched it all together.  It did not look like that while I was typing??